# Alteração do width do frame com mouse over javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Olá, preciso fazer um código em javascript que altere o width do meu iframe ao passar o mouse por cima desse iframe.

Eis o código:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.site.com.br/imagens/style.css">
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=600,height=250">
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTag = "http://www.site.com.br"; </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
        <img src="http://www.site.com.br/imagens/delta.gif"  class="image; image-a" border="0" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="http://www.site.com.br/imagens/fotogrande.jpg"  border="0" />
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alterar para qual valor? Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: O iframe inicial é estruturado com 300x250, através do mouseover o iframe deve mudar para 600x20 (width x heigh). Preciso dessa função over que faça com que o width o iframe altere, quando o mouse sai da área do iframe o tamanho volta ao inicial.

Comment: Selecione todo o código fonte, depois click no botão `{ }` para ele aparecer formatado.

Comment: Obrigada. Já coloquei o código :)

Answer (score 1):

você consegue este efeito com o seguinte css.:

```css
#meuframe {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#meuframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  transition: width 500ms linear, height 500ms linear 500ms;
}

#meuframe:hover {
  width: 600px;
  height: 125px;
  transition: height 500ms linear, width 500ms linear 500ms;  
}
```

```html
<iframe id="meuframe" src="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ou com javascript:

```js
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
frame.onmouseover = function() {
  frame.style.width = '600px';
  frame.style.height = '20px';
}
```

```css
#frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id='frame' src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Desse jeito eu devo ter duas index.html? Uma com meu código principal e outra com a função js e a tag do iframe? Ou fica tudo numa página só?

Comment: O código que altera o frame deve ir na página que contém o frame @mab. A página que irá no `src` do frame é outra, sim.

Comment: Certo, foi o que eu fiz. Mas não deu certo, ele carrega a página dentro iframe mas com a barra de altura e largura, com altura inferior a de 250px. Não está ajustando o frame quando passa o mouse :(

Comment: Consegue criar um Fiddle @mab?

Comment: Consegui sim.. mas no Fiddle ele funcionou. Quando eu coloco os arquivos online, não funciona corretamente. Olha o print. http://prntscr.com/fknkd8